# In an Android Fragment, why is a call to superclass not made on `onCreateView`?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragment-lifecycle

Reading through "Head First Android Development", I noticed this issue on page 367.

The code is an implementation of a Fragment, and a couple of life cycle methods are overridden, namely `onCreateView` and `onStart`.

`onStart()` looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  ...
}
```

whereas `onCreateView` looks like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout_detail, container, false);
}
```

Notice that `onStart` includes a call to the overridden method, via `super.onStart()`, whereas `onCreateView` does not call its overridden method.

**Why does `onStart` make the `super` call, while `onCreateView` does not?**

Also on this page, there is bold text, reading:

> You should always call up to the superclass when you implement any fragment lifecycle methods.

If this is the case, then why does the `onCreateView` method not call up to the superclass?

The page in question is shown below.

[image: The page in question; Head First Android page 367]

Comment: That statement is patently wrong - you have never needed to call `super.onViewCreated()` (which is actually where you should be setting your Fragment's view to its proper state, not `onStart()`) - the methods that need to call super are marked with the `@CallSuper` annotation. Anything not marked with that annotation does not need to call super.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That comment is correct. You should **always** call the superclass lifecycle method. because they do stuff.
`onCreateView` of Fragment is as follow:

[image: onCreateView]

That `mContentLayoutId` is a layout Res id which you can in fragment's constructor:
[image: Fragment's secondary constructor]

What it does is to inflate the resource layout `mContentLayoutId` which you can pass to fragment's Constructor and return the result, and if not set return null.

because you want to inflate your layout, you do not need this. You can call it though, but it has no effect (unless you pass a layout resource to fragment constructor and want to do something with the return view, which **I do not recommend** because `onViewCreated` exists.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does onStart make the super call, while onCreateView does not?

The short answer is your book is probably old.

If you check the source code, [you see that onCreateView only does something if you provide a layout resource ID](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.java;l=1992). It's expected that you will provide a view yourself so calling the super class serves no purpose if you're overriding the method. Moreover, `onCreateView` used to not even do that much, it would just return null, so calling it served no purpose. That's probably how it worked when your book was written.

By comparison, [you can see that onStart not only has logic](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.java;l=3081), but actively checks if you've called it (`mCalled = true`) and [throws an exception if you didn't call it](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.java;l=3082).

So for some methods it's optional to call through to `super` and won't have any effect, while others it's basically required (or you get an Exception).

Comment: You've linked to the framework Fragment class (`android.app.Fragment`), which has been deprecated for years and something no one should ever use. It is the [source for AndroidX Fragments](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.java) that you should be looking at.

Comment: Good point, thanks. Just Googled for the source and didn't think twice. Links updated.